# Connect socket to loopback remote endpoint while bound to LAN source address

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, sockets, bind

I'm looking for some help in understanding how to connect an outbound socket to a destination IP on the 127.x.x.x loopback subnet while bound to a "real" IP assigned to the local machine.

I cannot bind a socket to have local endpoint 10.0.0.1 (the workstation's only non-loopback  IPv4 address) and connect to "remote" server (which is listening OK) at address 127.4.5.6.  I see winsock error 10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) and the .net framework pukes with "The requested address is not valid in its context 127.4.5.6:50000"

Details.

I have a local socket that connects to a remote server.  I have to bind the source address of my socket to a specific local address.  This is because the machine that runs the socket might have many address available to it, but only one source IP address is NAT'd correctly so that the remote server trusts it.  I cannot bind the local socket to any old local address because the O/S might choose one that is not NAT'd and so the remote server doesn't like the source address.

Functionally this all works fine.

I am trying to unit test it.  Since mocking and subclassing sockets is not possible, my unit test spawns a local EXE that acts as the remote server, listening on a particular loopback address (defined in command line parameters) such as 127.4.5.6.  I can then connect my main program to that "remote" address 127.4.5.6 while the source is bound to 127.1.2.3.   This all works fine.

But I want to make a change to allow the fake server (the EXE) to still listen on 127.4.5.6 while forcing the outbound socket that's being unit tested to bind locally to 10.0.0.1 (the workstation's LAN IP) rather than 127.1.2.3. Windows doesn't like it - it throws a Winsock 10049 error, saying that the address is not valid in its context.

How can I connect to a remote endpoint of a loopback address while locally bound to a local endpoint of a regular LAN address please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question before on Microsoft forum. This happens on Microsoft's new TCPIP implementation (IPv6 on all OS, and IPv4 on Vista and laters).
Loopback to non-loopback should work fine on XP over IPv4.

See [why can't we connect to loopback address from non loopback addresses anymore?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b280699-fa48-4461-8875-bb446b6ea48a/why-cant-we-connect-to-loopback-address-from-non-loopback-addresses-anymore?forum=wfp) for Microsoft explanations.